# input created based on user specific option does not submit in post method

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post, submit

I created a form. it has a dropdown. if a specific option selected, some inputs will create dynamically.
the problem is that the dynamically created inputs don't submit in post method to php script.
here is my code:

```
<script>
            function forn(that) {
                if (that.value == "ps")
                {
                    var x = document.getElementById("xx");
                    var rr = document.getElementById("rtrt");
                    var trtr = document.createElement("div");
                    trtr.id += "trtr";
                    trtr.className += "col-sm-3  form-group";
                    var input1 = document.createElement("input");
                    input1.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
                    input1.name = "_fr";
                    input1.style.marginTop = "3em";
                    trtr.appendChild(input1);
                    var label = document.createElement("label");
                    label.className += "form-control-label mbr-fonts-style display-7";
                    label.innerText = "yes";
                    label.style.marginRight = "0.5em";
                    var br = document.createElement("br");
                    trtr.appendChild(label);
                    x.insertBefore(trtr, rr.nextSibling);
                }else { $("div").remove("#trtr"); }

            }
        </script>
```

and my form submits using ajax to php:

```
<script>
        $(document).on('click', '#calc', function (e) {
            var data = $("#form-pay").serialize();
            alert(data);
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                data: data,
                cache: false,
                type: "post",
                url: "calc_price.php",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("div").remove("#estelam");
                    var form = document.getElementById("xx");
                    var div = document.createElement('div');
                    var btns = document.getElementById("btns");
                    div.id += "estelam";
                    div.className += "alert alert-success";
                    div.style += "display:inline-block;";
                    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode("data));
                    form.insertBefore(div, btns);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

thank you for your help.

Comment: Is `#xx` placed within the form?

Comment: @Teemu interesting! wow! OMG! you solved my problem by just asking a question. thank you very much.